# Zoho JSON result into CSV file

Tags: php, json, csv, zoho

I'm trying to turn a JSON result into a CSV file, however, I keep getting trying to get property of non-object

**Here is the code**

```
$url = file_get_contents('https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/json/Contacts/getRecords?authtoken=myAPIkey&scope=crmapi');
$data = json_decode($url);
$r = $data->response->result->Contacts->row->no[1];
//Give our CSV file a name.
$csvFileName = 'example.csv';
//Open file pointer.
fopen($csvFileName,'a');

//Loop through the associative array.
foreach($r as $row) {
    $values = array_column($row['columns'], 'value');
    fputcsv($fp, $values);
} 


//Finally, close the file pointer.
fclose($fp);
```

Here is a sample of the JSON response

```
{
  "response": {
    "result": {
      "Contacts": {
        "row": [
          {
            "no": "1",
            "FL": [
              {
                "val": "CONTACTID",
                "content": "3508588000000206016"
              },
              {
                "val": "SMOWNERID",
                "content": "3508588000000176021"
              },
              {
                "val": "Contact Owner",
                "content": "Chris Yates"
              },
              {
                "val": "First Name",
                "content": "Bob"
```

Naturally, I'd like it to go through each row and save to the CSV

Thanks in advance, I've looked through a few solutions on SO but none seem to work for me

Comment: Are you getting the error in this line? `$r = $data->response->result->Contacts->row->no[1];`

Comment: @TamilvananN - Yes, I know thats whats causing the problem I just can't seem to find the correct structure

Comment: `->row->no[1];` it's wrong as per your json structure

Comment: Yes I know that - I'd notmally use 
$data->response->result->Contacts->row[1]->FL[2]->content;
To get data from individual rows & specific elements
but I'm struggling with this

Comment: Is there any other key apart from "no" & "FL" inside "row"?

Comment: nope just those 2
I have also tried $r = $data->response->result->Contacts->row; and then print_r which is displaying all as an array but I still am unsure how to do this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180428/discussion-between-chris-yates-and-tamilvanan-n).

Comment: I suppose I could always declare variables for the data I want inside the loop like
$name = $row->FL[2]->content;
that would work but it's not ideally what I'd want but it's something I can work with i suppose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's check the below code.

```
<?php
$json = '{"response":{"result":{"Contacts":{"row":[{"no":"1","FL": 
[{"val":"CONTACTID","content":"3508588000000206016"}, 
{"val":"SMOWNERID","content":"3508588000000176021"},{"val":"Contact 
Owner","content":"Chris Yates"},{"val":"First Name","content":"Bob"}]}]}}}}';
$data = json_decode($json,true);
$rows = $data['response']['result']['Contacts']['row'];
$csvFileName = 'example.csv';
$fp = fopen($csvFileName,'a');
foreach($rows as $row) {
foreach($row['FL'] as $fls) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fls);
}
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Yeah the issue I had was that if a value wasnt defined for an element for example if Account Name was blank it would screw the csv file up as the data wouldnt match up to other rows
I am defining each element and if its blank it'll be set to '' so $blah = ''
but at least then when I build the data string it will still count the column

Comment: I'll accept your answer though because it does work but just isn't fool proof for what I need, thanks for your help though :)